# How to update a table DB from a custom class bound on DataGridView in C#

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq, datagridview, ado.net

I try to explain better using an example:

- I create the class **Product** with attibutes like that:

  ```
  private string _ProductCode = "";
  [DisplayName("ProductCode")]
  public String ProductCode
  {
    get { return _ProductCode; }
    set { _ProductCode = value; OnPropertyChanged("ProductCode"); }
  }
  ```
- the class Product implements the interfaces: **INotifyPropertyChanged**, **IEditableObject**
- I create the class **ProductList** that has the following property:

  ```
  public List<Product> Products { get; set; }
  ```
- I bind the class Product in a *DataGridView* control using the *DataSource* property

  ```
  MyGridView.DataSource = ProductList.Products;
  ```
- I create the table **ProductListTable** on db SqlServer
- When I push the button "Save" on my form I'd would like to save the ProductList on ProductListTable

Data is loaded directly on DataGrid for the first time.
But I could also retrieve it from ProductListTable, then modify on DataGrid, and finally save the changes.

I'm really confusing about the way to follow ... I have to use Link 2 Sql, Entity Framework?
I'm searching for something simple for a small project, but using POCO classes for rapresenting the data layer.

Now how I should proceed for linking class to DB table?

Comment: If you're asking for design input, you might want to try [CodeReview](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/). If you're running into problems with a specific implementation, please post the code where you're having issues as well as information about the specific issue. Without that information, this question would tend towards an opinion poll.

Comment: I'm searching for some code samples ...

Comment: Anyway I posted on CodeReview the question: http://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/30023/28711